# Is it possible to clone a git repo without the .git folder, into an existing non empty directory

Tags: git

I have an odd use case, and am not very familiar with Git. I have two git repos; repo one which is empty, and repo two which has files. I also have a folder ./foo. I want something similar to this:

```
cd ./foo
git clone repo_one .
git clone repo_two . (I just want the files from repo_two. No .git folder or anything)
git add --a
git push repo_one
```

or maybe

```
cd ./foo
git clone repo_two .
rm ./.git
git clone repo_one . (possible in an existing directory though?)
```

Are either of these possible? All I really care about is the end result; that .foo is linked to repo_one, but contains the files from repo_two.

Comment: You are aware that you will loose all the history of those files, and if you change something in one repository, you will have to also do it in the second one? An option might be to use submodules to "link" as you called it one repository into the other one. This way you keep the history, you only have to do changes once, but still have the files directly accessible in the (now) empty repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've cloned both the Git repos, execute the following command on repo #2 to export (or archive) it without its `.git` folder:

```
git archive master | tar -x -C /path/inside/repo1
```

The final sequence of events would be something like this:

```
cd foo
git clone repo_one
git clone repo_two
cd repo_two
git archive master | tar -x -C ../repo_1
```

Answer (score 0):

`git clone` has an option `--separate-git-dir=` which puts the `.git` directory somewhere else, but it creates a file named `.git` in the checkout directory, which references the relocated .git-directory.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---separate-git-dirltgitdirgt

Answer (score 0):

Check this helpful blog post about the bundle and archive in general: https://www.perforce.com/blog/git-beyond-basics-bundle-and-archive

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is best to always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).